# jquery slideToggle next() не работает на все елементы

Tags: jquery

```js
$(".dropdown").live('click', function() {
  if ($(this).closest("li").next().find("ul").length) {
    $(this).next("ul").slideToggle(200)
  }
  return false
});
```

```css
.side-block .nav-ul li a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 8px 10px 8px 27px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #6887a7;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.side-block .nav-ul li a:after {
  content: "";
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #134b67;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: 14px;
  top: 14px;
}

.side-block .nav-ul li:last-child a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.side-block .nav-ul li {
  position: relative;
}

.side-block .nav-ul li.dropdown:before {
  top: 14px;
  right: 0;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-top-color: #134b67;
  border-width: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.noarrow:before {
  display: none;
}

.side-block .nav-ul ul {
  /* display: none;*/
  background: #f4f4f4;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.side-block .nav-ul ul li a {
  padding: 8px 10px 8px 38px;
  color: #454545;
}

.side-block .nav-ul ul li a:after {
  left: 24px;
}

.side-block .nav-ul ul ul {
  /* display: none;*/
  background: #f4f4f4;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #384453;
  border-top: 1px solid #384453;
}

.side-block .nav-ul ul ul li a {
  padding: 8px 10px 8px 45px;
  color: #454545;
}

.side-block .nav-ul ul ul li a:after {
  left: 35px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav-ul">
  <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">menu 1</a></li>
  <ul style="display: none;">
    <li class="dropdown"><a class="" href="#">level 2</a></li>
    <ul style="display: none;">
      <li><a class="" href="#">level 3</a></li>
      <li><a class="" href="#">level 3 second</a></li>
    </ul>
    <li><a class="" href="#">level 2 second</a></li>
  </ul>

  <li><a href="#">menu 2</a></li>

  <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">menu 3</a></li>
  <ul style="display: none;">
    <li><a class="" href="#">Sub level 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

как сделать, чтоб работал меню на все ссылки **dropdown**, работает он только для первой **menu 1** 
писал все сам, может где-то добавить надо чего-нибудь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        $(function () {
            $(".dropdown").on('click', function () {
                $(this).next("ul").slideToggle(200)
                return false;
            });
        });

P.S. Метод live () стал устаревшим в jQuery версии 1.7 и удален в версии 1.9. Вместо этого используйте метод on().
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: спосибо, все работает как надо

Answer (score 0):

Каким образом надо сделать чтобы при клике на другой ссылке закрыть предыдущие но при этом если кликать и под меню то не закрыть старшего меню

вот код я тут попробовал но не выходит

```
$(".nav-ul .dropdown").on('click', function () {

    var that = $(this).next("ul");
    $('.nav-ul').each(function() {
        if(that == $(this).next("ul")) return true;
        $(this).next("ul").slideToggle(200);
    });
    $(this).next("ul").slideToggle(200);
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('up down');
    return false;

});
```